# Installing NumPy on Snow Leopard (10.6) with XCode 4 installed

Tags: python, macos, xcode4, numpy, osx-snow-leopard

I can't seem to install NumPy to System Python now that I've upgraded to Xcode 4.

When I try to do:

```
easy_install -U numpy
```

I get:

```
File "/private/tmp/easy_install-xoqh9U/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/core/setup.py", line 696, in get_mathlib_info
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

I'd like to use System Python (I have many other modules compiled/installed, and don't want to use EPD for this purpose).

Answer (score 0):

you have download tar.gz file from the site unzip it and then move that folder to any of the pythonpath

which you can get by typing

sys.path